# Android : AsyncTask not reaching onPostExecute

Tags: android, android-asynctask, countdownlatch

I am using AsyncTask to avoid networkonmainthreadexception on my Android Library Project, now what I want to do is to get the value to be returned to my variable and wait for it before executing the next line of code. I used CountDownLatch to do this.

The way I execute my request and call my AsyncTask is written below.. So I used CountDownLatch to wait for the response before returning the value that I want to return.

```
public MyObject getMyObject(){

    final String url = "http://[myip]:8080/retrieve";

    try{
        Response response = executeRequest(url);
        final MyObject myObject = om.readValue(response.body().string(),
                new TypeReference<MyObject>() {
                });
        return myObject;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;

}



private Response executeRequest(String url){

    try {
      //Simplified please just ignore this..
      GenericAsyncParams genericAsyncParams = createParams(......);

      final CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
      ResponseListener responseListener = new ResponseListener(countDownLatch);
      MyAsyncTask myAsyncTask = new AsyncTask(responseListener);
      myAsyncTask.execute(genericAsyncParams);
      countDownLatch.await();

      //get the response from the listener class.
      Response response = responseListener.getResponse();
      return response;
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
  }
```

I am also aware that **asyncTask.execute(args).get()** could cause the exception, so I used a listener to update the value from the caller, I call setResponse on onPostExecute of my AsyncTask.

```
public class ResponseListener {

    private static final String TAG = ResponseListener.class.getName();

    private Response response;
    private CountDownLatch countDownLatch;

    public ResponseListener(CountDownLatch countDownLatch) {
        this.response = null;
        this.countDownLatch = countDownLatch;
    }

    public void setResponse(Response response){
        this.response = response;   
        Log.e(TAG, "Executing countdown..");
        countDownLatch.countDown();
    }

    public Response getResponse() {
        return response;
    }

    public CountDownLatch getCountDownLatch() {
        return countDownLatch;
    }
}
```

Now this is my AsyncTask
Note: requestProcessor is a wrapper class for okHttp.

```
public class MyAsynctask extends AsyncTask<GenericAsyncParams, Void, Response>{


    private static final String TAG = MyAsyncTask.class.getName();

    private ResponseListener listener;

    public MyAsynctask(ResponseListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    protected Response doInBackground(GenericAsyncParams... genericAsyncParamses) {
        Response response = null;
        GenericAsyncParams genericAsyncParams = genericAsyncParamses[0];
        String url = genericAsyncParams.getUrl();
        String method = genericAsyncParams.getMethod();
        RequestProcessor requestProcessor = genericAsyncParams.getRequestProcessor();

        try {
            Request.Builder builder;
            if(method.equalsIgnoreCase("POST")){
                builder = new Request.Builder()
                        .post(genericAsyncParams.getRequestBody())
                        .url(url)
                        .headers(headers);
            } else  {
                builder = new Request.Builder()
                        .headers(headers)
                        .get()
                        .url(url);
            }
            final Request request = builder.build();
            response = requestProcessor.client().newCall(request).execute();
            Log.d(TAG, "returning okHttp response..");
            return response;
        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.e(TAG, String.format("ERROR.. %s", ExceptionUtils.getMessage(e)));
        }

        return response;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Response response) {
        if(listener != null){
            Log.d(TAG, "Updating response : onPostExecute..");
            listener.setResponse(response);
        } else {
            super.onPostExecute(response);
        }
    }

}
```

The last line of my log is

```
07-10 23: 47:07.008 28409-28530/com.aaron.android.android.lib D/com.aaron.android.android.lib.api.tasks.MyAsyncTask: returning okHttp response..
```

Comment: What class contains `executeRequest()`?

Comment: It is a common code inside a Util class used throughout the project.

Comment: Please show that in your code and show an example of how it is called.

Comment: Are you expecting an Activity calling it? this is a library project by the way.

Comment: Yes, I am guessing that an Activity or Service calls `executeRequest()`. You need to show more code in order to clarify this. Please give a [mcve].

Comment: I just updated it and I guess, it's the last part of code on which I could share.

Comment: Please read the link that I gave in my previous comment.

Comment: Your current code is not complete. When I copy and paste it into Android Studio, I get compiler errors because there are methods outside of a class. Also, we need an example of how the methods are called. Everything in Android starts from a lifecycle method. You need to show an example of one of these.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NetworkOnMainException` reminds us to not block the main UI thread. However, you are still blocking it by using a `CountDownLatch` to wait for the response. Since `onPostExecute()` runs on the main thread, you have blocked it from executing. You cannot block the main thread while waiting for the network connection to finish. Instead, allow `executeRequest()` to return so that the UI can respond appropriately.

Comment: I think this makes sense to me now, so I have to refactor my code because currently, the only Async part of it is the interface that I expose to the Application Project. Other components such as network calls are not asynchronous, and I wait for each return value on the services (not android services, but just services) that I use to collect the data that I need to be returned to the API (what my library is for) that I created. Anyway, this is very big help and I have a lot of refactoring to do. Thanks @Code-Apprentice !